# one to many relation-displays first row only

Tags: php, mysql

after going through many attempts, i finally can display data from child table. I have 2 tables, user (parent) and useradvert(child).

user
-id (pk)
-name
-username
-telno

useradvert
-id(index) 
etc.........

it's a 1 to many relation. from table users to table useradvert. table users suppose to pull many rows from table useradvert based on specific id which matches id in table users. But, instead it only display first row from useradvert. No matter how you login with different username, you will always see the first row from useradvert and not the rows that is supposed to display. For ur info, I'm a newbie. Any help is appreciated. tqs.

below is extract;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users,useradvert WHERE users.id=useradvert.id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 
$row2 = $res->fetch_array();


$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
$_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
$_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
$_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
$_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
$_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];
```

below is extract -continue on same page

```
 <?php
  //display record from table- useradveret -(child table)
//    while($row = $res->fetch_array()){



    echo $_SESSION['name2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['color2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['hobby2']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['radiobtn']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['kupon']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['image2']."<br/>";
//  }
```

?>

table query for useradvert

### -- Table structure for table `useradvert`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `useradvert` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hobby2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `radiobtn` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `kupon` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `useradvert`
--

INSERT INTO `useradvert` (`id`, `name2`, `color2`, `hobby2`, `radiobtn`, `kupon`, `image`, `image2`) VALUES
(97, 'testthree nickname', 'colorthree', 'hobbythree', 'female', '', 'uploads/testpic1.jpg', 'uploads/testpic2.jpg'),
(99, 'testfivenamecick', 'testfivehcolor', 'testfivecolor', 'female', '', 'uploads/testpic3.jpg', 'uploads/testpic4.jpg'),
(97, 'lagitestthree', 'trheecolor', 'threehobby', 'female', '', 'uploads/testpic5.jpg', 'uploads/testpic6.jpg');

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `useradvert`
--
ALTER TABLE `useradvert`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `useradvert_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

Comment: Try to use `$row2 = $res->fetch_array();` like `while($row2 = $res->fetch_array()){ //Your code }`

Comment: hi to both. tq.. i don't get it.. what do u mean? @Saty. Please correct me if im wrong.. SELECT * FROM user.-->I select * FROM...which suppose to mean all columns right?

Comment: I think i did select all columns. please correct me if im wrong..

Comment: Hi..tq @Kausha Mehta.. Which part?? currently im disabling the while part. I just wanna fetch the echoed display data based on their id's.

Comment: Write `print_r($res); die;` after `$res = $stmt->get_result();` line and let me know what it displays. You can edit your question and add output at the end....

Comment: Hi @bdiffirent. tq for sharing. I might be wrong. Please correct me. I thought the id in useradvert is the foreign key as well as the index key. Because in sql, i put it as index key and related it to id(PK) in users thus automatically becomes foerign key when i related them

Comment: Hi @Kausha Mehta mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 )

Comment: @ Kausha Mehta The reading is above..i pasted..

Comment: Ok, Now write like this `while($row2 = $res->fetch_array()){ print_r($row2); die(); }` and let me know the OP.

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 )

Comment: `$res` and `$res->fetch_array()` are not return same result? First read my commnet.

Comment: @Kausha Mehta. Yes it gave same result.

Comment: Ok, `while($rowdata = $res->fetch_array()){ print_r($rowdata); die(); }` and let me know ehat it returns... May be it conflicts variable name..... may be....

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 ) still same sa previous

Comment: Try simple `mysql_query()` or `mysqli_query()` in place of `$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); $stmt->execute();` and check what it OP.

Comment: Hi..@kausha Mehta . I tried what u suggested but i removed the die; Now i get all results from table left (parent) and table right(child)..I ran-->while($row2 = $res->fetch_array())

    {print_r ($row2); }

Comment: It's giving me all result from both table. I think you are right @Kausah Mehta. I might see some light at the end of the tunnel. You are leading me to the right direction..I'm not good at if while loop condition. How do I echo the results from the right table only (specific rows matching to the left table)? I think it has something to do with if while loop conditions..(maybe )...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your sql query is not correct. Yo use the id field of useradvert table, but that is the index field of that table. That looks wrong. You should have a foreign key userId in useradvert table for the join. Then you query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN useradvert ua ON u.id = ua.userId
```

Then you should get all useradvert fields for the user.

The 2 tables should look something like this:

Table user:

```
id | name | ... 
1 | Ben | ... 
2 | Markus | ...
```

Table useradvert:

```
id | userid | ... 
1 | 1 | ... 
2 | 1 | ...
```

userid in useradvert is the foreign key to create the relationship between the 2 tables. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can u provide further explanation.  
 tq for sharing @bdifferent. I might be wrong. Please correct me. I thought the id in useradvert is the foreign key as well as the index key. Because in sql, i put it as index key and related it to id(PK) in users thus automatically becomes foerign key when i related them

Comment: So, do i ignore the id (index key) in useradvert and use any field (treat it as foreign key as long as it is not id (index) and join it to id-users)..

Comment: if i display my sql query table here..would it help??tqs

Comment: hello? @bdiferent. sorry for troubling you. but can u be more specific?..pls tq.

Comment: the index in useradvert cannot be the foreign key. You want to have one userid field where in multiple rows the same value is stored, thus to have multiple advert rows for one user. the index id is a unique field, working as the primary key of the table. Yes, definitely helps if you display the useradvert table

Comment: So, @bdifferent. What ur trying to say here is, i should create a new column e.g user_id (for useradvert) auto increment which will have multiple rows..because the id (index) in useradvert is unique and works as primary key so it cannot be interrupted ..I apologize for my bad english. So the solution here is just create another column after the id (index) in useradvert and make it as a foreign key. it will be named as userid (autoincrement)..am i right?

Comment: You would need to have the following:
Table user:
id | name | ...
1 | Ben | ...
2 | Markus | ...

Table useradvert:
id | userid | ...
1 | 1 | ...
2 | 1 | ...

userid in useradvert is the foreign key to create the relationship between the 2 tables. Does that make sense?
Put this into the original answer, formatting is not that good in the comments.

Comment: im so sorry @bdifferent. Im totally a newbie. I cannot understand your charts..Table user: id | name | ... 1 | Ben | ... Table useradvert: id | userid | ... 1 | 1 2 |...is there a better and simple explanation?..this is too advance..

Comment: Look in the answer, also you might want to read about foreign keys http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: What do u mean when u said "You would need to have the following: ....etc"...do u mean i need to add a new column like i said previously?..thats al i need to know etc.. a simple explanation.

Comment: ok read ur table in notepad.. i get it already.. but can u be more "straight to the point" and make the point "clear"....i see there's a column userid in useradvert.. so im right.. thats all right?